# Acceder mediante IP y PUERTO redireccionar a URL

Tags: linux, servidor, gps, cpanel, vps

Tengo un VPS linux con CPANEL y WHM instalado.
Por otro lado tengo un gps que envia señar al server, en el gps se puede configurar una IP y un puerto y el aparato envia un string que el servidor procesara y guardara en la base de datos.

Ya esta listo en un archivo .php y en un archivo phyton el procesamiento de este string (esta hecho en ambos solamente para probar en cual funciona mejor).

La pregunta es, puedo configurar el server (mediante CPANEL, WHM, SSH), que al ingresar por IP y tal puerto redireccione automantecamente a la ruta de los archivos que procesaran el string? (enviando las variables y demas).

Gracias!!!

Comment: Creo que al final lo solucione, lo que hice fue un script en Python qu escucha el puerto 333 (ejemplo), entonces al ingresar a www.miweb.com:333 el script escucha y redirecciona a otra url y hace lo que debe.

Es correto o hay alguna mejor forma??